# Using Jquery to append a li to an ul where oid=xxx

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-append

I am trying to append a li to only the UL which has a certain oid value set like this

```
$('ul.sortablespm oid=' + data).append('<li></li>');
```

It works fine without the oid parameter, but then adds the li to all ULs on the page..

Comment: Try `$('ul.sortablespm[oid="' + data + '"]').append('<li></li>');`

Comment: Can you show us your HTML please?  Then, we can try solutions ourselves and see what you really have and provide solutions without guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the appropriate **[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)** syntax, that is, [`[name="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('ul.sortablespm[oid="' + data + '"]').append('<li></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what I believe you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/chapmanc/wU6Vs/

If the ul object has a unique id you can simply use that as your selector and append an item to that object.

For example a ul with an id of myList:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>​
```

And a function to append to that object using the unique selector:

```
$('#myList').append('<li>d</li>');​
```

This appends a li item to the myList object. Notice the '#' character in front of myList when using an id selector.